# How to redirect with messages to display them in Django Templates?

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-templates

I have a view that validates and saves a form. After the form is saved, I'd like redirect back to a list_object view with a success message "form for customer xyz was successfully updated..."

HttpResponseRedirect doesn't seem like it would work, because it only has an argument for the url, no way to pass dictionary with it.

I've tried modifying my wrapper for object_list to take a dict as a parameter that has the necessary context.  I the return a call to this wrapper from inside the view that saves the form.  However, when the page is rendered, the url is '/customer_form/' rather than '/list_customers/'.  I tried modifying the request object, before passing it to the object_list wrapper, but that did not work.

Thanks.

Comment: Note to future searchers: Be sure to read on past the accepted answer, as it is now deprecated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Please note the answer suggested here is only applicable to Django < 1.2:**

Do you have control over the view that you are redirecting to? In that case you can save the context in the session before redirecting. The target view can pick up the context (and delete it) from the session and use it to render the template.

If your *only* requirement is to display a message then there is a better way to do this. Your first view can create a message for the current using `auth` and have the second view read and delete it. Something like this:

```
def save_form(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # all goes well
    message = _("form for customer xyz was successfully updated...")
    request.user.message_set.create(message = message)
    return redirect('list_view')

def list_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Render page

# Template for list_view:
{% for message in messages %}
   ... 
{% endfor %}
```

Messages are saved to the database. This means that you can access them even after a redirect. They are automatically read *and* deleted on rendering the template. You will have to use `RequestContext` for this to work.

**For Django => 1.2 read the answer involving messages**

Comment: The other answer should probably be accepted as the correct answer now. This was deprecated in django 1.2 and removed in django 1.4 (as mentioned in the other answer).

Answer (score 83):

`request.user.message_set` was deprecated in Django 1.2 and has been removed since Django 1.4, the [message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/messages/) should be used instead.

```
from django.contrib import messages

# messages.add_message(request, level, message, extra_tags='', fail_silently=False)
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Your Message")
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the [shortcut functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-a-message):

```
from django.contrib import messages

messages.debug(request, "Your Message")
messages.info(request, "Your Message")
messages.success(request, "Your Message")
messages.warning(request, "Your Message")
messages.error(request, "Your Message")
```

Messages can then be rendered on the template with:

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I would add that you can use `{{ message.level_tag }}` to show the level tag. success etc. which can be useful tor styling `alert-{{ message.level_tag }}` for instance

Answer (score 15):

To expand on Antoine's helpful answer: if you want to process the messages in your views module, rather than the template:

```
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages

def my_view(request):
    # Process your form data from the POST, or whatever you need to do

    # Add the messages, as mentioned above
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, form.cleaned_data['name'])

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/other_view_url/')

def other_view(request):
    storage = get_messages(request)
    name = None
    for message in storage:
        name = message
        break
    return render(request, 'general/other_view.html', {'name': name})
```

Answer (score 2):

In Django 2.x + you can simply use messages framework that comes with Django

`views.py`

```
from django.contrib import messages

def register(request):
    ....
    messages.success(request,"You have registered successfully, now login!")
    return redirect('login-page')
```

And in you, login.html template do add this code

```
  {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show">
            <strong>Success!</strong> {{message}}
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
```

Note this example can be applied to anywhere you want to display a message for success

If you want to pass an error message simply use `messages.error(request, "Error message")`

Answer (score 1):

I found the following to work if more than just a message needs to be added to the redirect:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
import urllib

def my_view(request):

    ...

    context = {'foo1': bar1, 'foo2': bar2, 'foo3': bar3}
    return redirect('/redirect_link/?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(context))
```

See also
[how to pass context data with django redirect function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564053/how-to-pass-context-data-with-django-redirect-function/34565763#34565763)

Answer (score 0):

To **Django Admin**, I could redirect with **the several types of messages** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.contrib import messages # Here
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request): 
    messages.debug(request, 'This is debug')
    messages.info(request, 'This is info')
    messages.success(request, 'This is success')
    messages.warning(request, 'This is warning')
    messages.error(request, 'This is error')
    return redirect("http://localhost:8000/admin/store/order/")
```

But, I don't know why only **"debug" message** is not displayed even though **"DEBUG = True"** in **"settings.py"**:

[image]