# How to pass context data with django redirect function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, redirect, django-templates

I have function which redirect to a URL.

```
return redirect('/orders')
```

The URL `/orders` has some context data which is being passed to it.
I want to pass some additional data along with data from the URL's function in view like:

```
return redirect('/orders', {'message':'some_message'})
```

I tried like this according to documentation:

```
return redirect('/orders', message='some_message')
```

But it didn't passed any data back to html.
So how to pass data with redirect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If its just a small item, like `?status=2` it can be added to the URL in the usual way. (small aside: careful, it may have a negative impact of how search engines spider your web site, i.e. create duplicate content issues)

However, for your example, passing an entire "message" string to the next page, I would recommend to do it the same way [Django's Messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/) does it: by using [Django's Session engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/).

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect with **session** using **request.session["key"]** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request): 
            # Here
    request.session["message"] = "some_message"
    return redirect('/orders')
```

```
# "index.html"

{{ request.session.message }} {# some_message #}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit bootleg, but works for my use-case. Using `session` but with a change. Once the redirect goes through, the session is deleted and the variable is passed down to the template as a context.

```py
class OAuthLoginErrorView(socialaccount_views.LoginErrorView):
    def get(self, request):
        request.session["error_login_error"] = True
        return redirect(reverse("account_login"))
```

```py
class LoginView(allauth_views.LoginView):
    def get(self, request):
        errors = list(filter(lambda arg: arg.startswith("error_"), request.session.keys()))
        if errors:
            for error in errors:
                del request.session[error]

            return render(
                request,
                self.template_name,
                context={
                    **self.template_settings,
                    **{error: True for error in errors},
                },
            )

        return super().get(request)
```

```html
{% if error_login_error %}
    <div class="text-sm text-red-500 font-center">There was an error logging-in.</div>
{% endif %}
```

Works for what I need.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `http redirect` (the case you mentioned), you need to pass your arguments through url's query string:

```
redirect('/orders?message=some_message')
```

Another ways is that you call other view with your custom parameter, which is not recommended generally.

Edit:
You can also use [django.sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/) to make central request-based messaging.

Answer (score -1):

I mean you can always use the `get_context_data` method to do that. This method will always sent the data from the view to the template.