# Unable to access a variable from one view to another view using functions?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have written a Registration form in Django. I'm trying to pass the name of the user getting registered successfully from the view1 (register_user) to view2 (register_success). So that the user can see his name on the registration successful page.
Below are the 2 views

View1

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
#Function for retrieving username from the form
            def give_username():
                return form.cleaned_data.get["username"]
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')

        else:
             form = UserCreationForm()
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request,'register.html',args)
```

View2

```
def register_success(request):
    full_name = register_user(request).give_username
    return render (request,'register_success.html',{'full_name':full_name})
```

register_success.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
           <h2>Hey {{ full_name }}, Greetings .. You have registered successfully !</h2>
           <p>Click <a href="/accounts/login/">here</a> to login again</p>
{% endblock %}
```

I am not using the sessions to store the variable as it can be a bad practice.
So when trying the above code, I get this error.

```
AttributeError at /accounts/register_success/
'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'give_username'
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register_success/
Django Version:     1.9.2
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value: 

'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'give_username'
Exception Location:     /home/harish/django/django/django_test/django_test/views.py in register_success, line 56
Python Executable:  /home/harish/django/django/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/harish/django/django/django_test',
 '/home/harish/django/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/harish/django/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg',
  '/home/harish/django/django/lib/python2.7']
Server time:    Thu, 4 Feb 2016 05:44:16 +0000
```

Where am I going wrong in accessing the username variable ?

Comment: You're a little off in your general approach. If you're writing a view for registration success, it won't get the form data from the registration form submission view. That's just not how the web works. I would handle this by fetching the user from the request on the success view, assuming you're using some version of the usual Django user package - that's a pretty well used path for identifying which user is making a given request. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user for the details.

Comment: @Peter DeGlopper Got your point, sir. So I tried using request.user.username in the success_register view and couldn't retrieve the username. Don't know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access arbitrary variable from a view by calling it from external view. You can pass the data as URL parameters or messages.

By using URL parameters:

```
def registration(request):
    do_registration()
    return redirect(reverse('registration_success') + '?u=%s' % get_username)

def registration_success(request):
    username = request.GET.get('u', None)
    return render(request, 'my_template', {'username': username})
```

Or by messages:

```
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages

def my_view(request):
    # Process your form data from the POST, or whatever you need to do

    # Add the messages, as mentioned above
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, form.cleaned_data['name'])

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/other_view_url/')

def other_view(request):
    storage = get_messages(request)
    name = None
    for message in storage:
        name = message
        break
    return render(request, 'general/other_view.html', {'name': name})
```

second snippet taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34653348/4726598).

Comment: Implemented your way and its  working nicely now. Kudos.