# Passing context to a Response and using it in a view

Tags: python, django

I am working on a web app and I want to use `HttpResponse` or `HttpResponseRedirect` instead of `render`. But I dont know hoe to pass context in response as it does not have context parameter like render. And also how to use the passed context in the url or view ?

Here is my **view**:

```
@login_required
def view_task_description(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_description = GetTaskDescription(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if task_description.is_valid():
            obj = GetTaskDescription.get_task_description(task_description)
            return render(request, 'todoapp/task_desc.html', context={'description': obj[0].description})
    return render(request, 'todoapp/select_task_description.html', context={'view_tasks': GetTaskDescription(user=request.user)})
```

I want to use Redirect or ResponseRedirect with the context instead of the render that I am returning if my form is valid. Basically render still shows the response as a POST method and I want the response to be a GET. How can I do so ? Thanks.

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624422/how-do-i-redirect-in-django-with-context#answer-34653348

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect in Django with context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624422/how-do-i-redirect-in-django-with-context)

Comment: Note that it would be much easier if you redirect to a view that takes the `obj` id in its URL since it seems you want to show a specific object: e.g. `return redirect('task_description_view', kwargs={'id': obj.id})`. Then in that view you can fetch the object and render _todoapp/task_desc.html_ passing the `obj.description` in the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new view for that. Then link it to the existing view using [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect). For example:

```
# view
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


@login_required
def get_task_description(request, pk):
   obj = get_object_or_404(TaskDescriptionModel, pk=pk)
   return render(request, 'todoapp/task_desc.html', context={'description': obj.description})

# url

url(r'^some_path/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', get_task_description, name="get_task_description")

# linking to existing view

 from django.shortcuts import redirect
 ...

     if task_description.is_valid():
        obj = GetTaskDescription.get_task_description(task_description)
        return redirect('get_task_description', pk=obj[0].pk)  # <-- Pointing the new view
```

Comment: I am using django 1.11. I dont know how path works as I have working with `url()` only

Comment: Its working but it wont show anything. I put the url as:  `url(r'^view_task_description/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.get_task_description, name="get_task_description")`

Comment: @Vai not sure what might go wrong. Is there any contents on `todoapp/task_desc.html`? Also can you please update your question with what you tried with? Thanks