# Django define URL using post request hidden value in UpdateView

Tags: django, url, input, view, hidden

I have an `UpdateView`, and want to redirect to an URL using a parameter based on POST request value, that is sending in this method.

For eg. ('clients:client_list', number_id)

It should be, the destination of the post function after define `is_valid()`.

Number_id is that I used in the `ListView` of the main foreign key model, and in my template it's a hidden input.

Comment: I can not properly understand your question. Can you give a clear picture what is the problem  you are facing? Paste some of your code so that proper answers can be given

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in Django. I just want to redirect after form_save() in POST method based on UpdateView, to url . This url has to use as parameter a hidden value in form sended.

Comment: @MuhammadHashirHassan I think it's should be easy but, couldn't do that redirection after post in my view. In PHP, when is received the post method you can do this with `Header("Location: query.php?user=".$user);` but, I can't do that on Django using ClassView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use following solutions to work with parameters:

- You can pass parameter to template using URL
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23932182/11979793

OR You can check out any of these solutions: [How do I redirect in Django with context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624422/how-do-i-redirect-in-django-with-context)

- You can use render to pass multiple parameters `return render(request, '../template_name', {'param1':<<value>>})`