# Show message in class based view in Django?

Tags: django

In function based view I can display some warning messages when the 2 passwords don’t match with each other or the email's already existed. But how can I do it in class based view. Noted that I use the custom form widgets.

how I do it in function based view

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        email = request.POST['email']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        # some other fields
        
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.info(request, 'Email is already taken')
            return redirect('register')
        elif password1 != password2:
             messages.warning(request, 'Passwords are not matched!')
             return redirect('register')
        elif form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             messages.success(request, 'Your account has created! You can log in now')
             return redirect('login')
```

how I write in forms.py

```
class form(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({
            'id': 'register-form',
            'placeholder': 'Email Address',
            'type': 'email',
            'name': 'email-register',
            'class': 'form-control mb-3 ml-3',
        })
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({
            'id': 'register-form',
            'placeholder': 'New Password',
            'type': 'password',
            'name': 'password1-register',
            'class': 'form-control mb-3 ml-3',
        })
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({
            'id': 'register-form',
            'placeholder': 'Re-enter New Password',
            'type': 'password',
            'name': 'password2-register',
            'class': 'form-control mb-3 ml-3',
        })
```

how I write in template

```
{% if messages %}
   {% for message in messages %}
   <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
      {{ message }}
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.email }}
{{ form.password1 }}
{{ form.password2 }}
<button type="submit">sign up</button>           
</form>
```

So How can I use the messages function in `class based` view?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624422/how-do-i-redirect-in-django-with-context
`messages.success(request,"error 123")` and then redirect....

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that question